# Active Record save or create command

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

```
$model = Person::findOne($person_id);
$model->status = $status;
$model->save();
```

or

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('person',
              ['status'=>$status],
              'person_id='.$person_id)
         ->execute();
```

In terms of performance, how this two snippet different from each other although the result is the same?

Answer (score 1):

The firts is based on the fact the related active record is obtained  by a preliminary select and then the change is performed  by an update    when the save() (and the related validation)  method is invoked ..

The second don't perform a select for get the related activeRecord ..

and perform the update only

so the second should be  more fast then the first ..

Answer (score 1):

Using ActiveRecord (the first example) is generally more memory intensive (because of the object setup, teardown, validation etcetera).

The second one will be much faster but it does not validate the data. Most of the time you will want to work with a "small" set of ActiveRecords objects (that's why Yii2 has pagination in it's DataProviders). ActiveRecord is more powerful since you can traverse relations, use virtual attributes etc.

But for batch inserts the second one it is much better. And you can also use it like this to insert multiple rows in one query:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('tableName', ['id', 'title', 'created_at'], [
    [1, 'title1', '2015-04-10'],
    [2, 'title2', '2015-04-11'],
    [3, 'title3', '2015-04-12'],
])->execute();
```